# Factorize 5 term polynomial with 2 variable. What method is the best?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I can't factorize this polynomial:$$ a^{4}-a^{3}b-7a^{2}b^{2}+ab^{3}+6b^{4}$$
I can't group it. And it have 2 variable. Help me!
Thank you.

Comment: For a start: $(a^2-b^2)(a^2-6b^2)-a^3b+ab^3$.  Try it from there.

Comment: First, note that all your terms are of order $4$, so if you divide it by $b^4$ it is a single variable polynomial in $\frac ab$.  Then the rational root theorem lets you find all the factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a homogeneous polynomial, so you can de-homogenise it, try to factot thz resulting polynomial in one variable and re-homogenise the factors.

Set $t=\frac ab$. The polynomial can be rewritten as
$$a^{4}-a^{3}b-7a^{2}b^{2}+ab^{3}+6b^{4}=b^4(t^4-t^3-7t^2+t+6).$$
Now, use the *rational roots theorem*: if the second factor has a rational root, it is a divisor of $6$. It is easy to see that $1$ and $-1$ are indeed roots, and performing the division we obtain
$$t^4-t^3-7t^2+t+6=(t^2-1)(t^2-t-6).$$
One also sees that $3$ is a root of the quadratic polynomial $t^2-t-6$, whence the other root is $-2$ (by Vieta's relations) and the final factorisation is
$$t^4-t^3-7t^2+t+6=(t-1)(t+1)(t+2)(t-3),$$
whence, teplacing $t$ and multiplying by $b^4$
$$a^{4}-a^{3}b-7a^{2}b^{2}+ab^{3}+6b^{4}=(a-b)(a+b)(a+2b)(a-3b).$$

Answer (score 2):

It is $$\left( -b+a \right)  \left( -3\,b+a \right)  \left( 2\,b+a \right) 
 \left( b+a \right) 
$$

Comment: Sir, What method that used to factorize it?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray} E &=&a^{4}-a^{3}b\underbrace{-a^{2}b^{2}-6a^2b^2}_{-7a^2b^2}+ab^{3}+6b^{4}\\
&=&a^{3}(a-b)-ab^{2}(a-b)-6b^2(a^2-b^{2})\\
&=&(a-b)(a^3-ab^2-6b^2(a+b))\\
&=&(a-b)(a(a^2-b^2)-6b^2(a+b))\\
&=&(a-b)(a+b)(a(a-b)-6b^2)\\
&=&(a-b)(a+b)(a^2-ab-6b^2)\\
&=&(a-b)(a+b)(a-3b)(a+2b)
\end{eqnarray}